# How can I replace the content of the browsers content with the xhr.responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the entire page's content using javacript or jquery and display the 404 html page returned by ajax request. Is that possible? How?

Comment: It's not possible to change the entire page, but it is possible to parse the response and replace all of the elements in `<head>` and `<body>` or more simply replacing `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, however be aware that scripts **will not** be unloaded

Comment: @PaulS. : It's okay if it's not loaded. I just want the 404 page to display and replace the current page. How can I do that?

Comment: `window.location = '/404.html';` is the easiest way

Comment: @PaulS.:  Is there a way I can use the xhr.responseText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [*DOMParser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to replace the contents of the *documentElement* with the *documentElement* from the *HTML* source in `xhr.responseText`

```
var dom = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/html');
// any attribute setting on `document.documentElement` etc here, then
document.documentElement.innerHTML = dom.documentElement.innerHTML;
dom = null;
```

---

Browser support of parsing *HTML* with *DOMParser* is

```
Google Chrome        30   +
Firefox              12   +
Internet Explorer    10   +
Opera                17   +
Safari                7.1 +
```

---

If you need to support legacy browsers consider instead of parsing, searching from the end for `</html>` and the start of the *String* for `<html`, finding the close `>` and then extracting everything between these two, which then gets set as the *innerHTML*

Answer (score 1):

Can use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which is simplest of the `$.ajax` shorthand methods

```
if( someCondition ){
    $('body').load('404.html');
}
```

This may or may not be what you are looking for as intent is not entirely clear in the question